# How can I make the relation I am using in a view work again?

Tags: views, 9

I'm currently migrating from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9, and i'm rebuilding all views (as I can't find a good migration procedure for views from 7 to 9), also trying to understand the changes (this is a side project for a friend, i'm not an expert in Drupal). I'm having difficulties with something I have running on 7. This is the situation on 7:

- I have a content type named "club" for sports clubs. Amongst other fields, it has the logo
- I have a content type named "club events". It includes a "club" field wich is an Entity Reference to said field.
- I have a view for displaying the events with the name and logo of the club. For the logo I created a relation in the view, to pick the image of the logo.

[image: Drupal 7 View working]

The results are as expected:

[image: Results, working]

After migrating the installation to Drupal 9, all content is there, all clubs have their logo, and all fields are ok. So I try to rebuild the view, but I can't make the relation to work. Here is the config of the relation in 9.4

[image: Building the relation]

And the view configuration in 9.4 with said relation for the image

[image: Relation in 9.4]

But the results don't show the image. If I set the "Behavior when no results" text to something, that text gets displayed, so it is not getting results out of the relation.

[image: no images loaded]

I'm stuck. I've been trying some options, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Anyone has any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution, just in case someone else has the same problem. I was making the relation wrong, it seems. When selecting the field, you have to check on "Content referenced from -the content type-". I was using another one :(

[image]